# *ngIf check time error Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular7

I am facing a weird error while checking `*ngIf` condition please help me.
    TestPlanComponent.html:115 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TestPlanComponent.html:116)
which is `*ngIf` statement.
and why always second condition comes to true as you can see it is always stop Icon.

```
<p-column field="run_now" header="Run Now" width="100px" 
   [style]="{ 'font-size': '12px;', width: '20px;' }" >
   <span 
      *ngIf="projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus !== 'RUNNING';
          then playButton else stopButton"></span> 
       <ng-template let-col let-j="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" #playButton>
           <img src="./assets/images/play-button.svg" class="material-icons playIcon" 
               (click)="testPlanExecute(projectList[j - page]?.id)" 
               title="{{ projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus }}"/>
       </ng-template>
       <ng-template let-col let-j="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" #stopButton>
           <img src="./assets/images/stop-button.svg" class="material-icons playIcon" 
               (click)="testPlanAbort(projectList[j - page]?.id)" 
               title="{{ projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus }}"/>
       </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

It is Mysterious error and does not tell any informative error.
[image]

Comment: you can move your ngIf condition logic to the method in the component and put the breakpoint there to debug it in the browser

Comment: it looks like that *ngIf condition also be executed when projectList is not valued. try in this way: *ngIf="projectList != null && projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus !== 'RUNNING';then playButton else stopButton"

Comment: and why always second condition is true whatever you do

Comment: why downvote without reason

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using optional chain in the `*ngIf`:

```
<span *ngIf="projectList && projectList[j - page] && 
     projectList[j - page].lastExecutionStatus !== 'RUNNING';
     then playButton else stopButton"></span>
```

`projectList[j - page]?` returns undefined and continue to next step `undefined.lastExecutionStatus` which throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
<p-column field="run_now" header="Run Now" width="100px" 
   [style]="{ 'font-size': '12px;', width: '20px;' }" >
   <span 
      *ngIf="projectList[j - page] && projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus !== 'RUNNING';
          then playButton else stopButton"></span> 
       <ng-template let-col let-j="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" #playButton>
           <img src="./assets/images/play-button.svg" class="material-icons playIcon" 
               (click)="testPlanExecute(projectList[j - page]?.id)" 
               title="{{ projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus }}"/>
       </ng-template>
       <ng-template let-col let-j="rowIndex" pTemplate="body" #stopButton>
           <img src="./assets/images/stop-button.svg" class="material-icons playIcon" 
               (click)="testPlanAbort(projectList[j - page]?.id)" 
               title="{{ projectList[j - page]?.lastExecutionStatus }}"/>
       </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your some of your variables are not initialized. So try to debug these variables and see values of these variables using `json` pipe:

```
<p> projectList {{ projectList | json }} </p>
<p> j {{ j | json}} </p>
<p> page {{ page | json  }} </p>

<span *ngIf="projectList && j && page 
    && projectList[j - page].lastExecutionStatus !== 'RUNNING';
    then playButton else stopButton">
</span>
```